# How can I authenticate user with JWT(JSON web token), while keeping the user in session and then log out?

Tags: angular, authentication, bootstrap-4, jwt, tokenize

I am a beginner in Angular and need to authenticate a user with JWT. In the login method I have only passed a string to validate user for login, for now as I haven't created a fake backend for testing. I would like to add token auth at later stage when I get this sorted out.

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const AUTH_API = 'https://localhost:8080/API/auth';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  [x: string]: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      if(username == 'x' && password == 'xxxxxx')
      observer.next({status: 'success'});
      else
      observer.next({status: 'failed'});
    });
  }

  register(username: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      AUTH_API + 'signup',
      {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      },
      httpOptions
    );
  }

  logout(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signout', { }, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

The problem is when I try to login, the user gets redirected to the profile but the navigation doesnt show logout button in the menu, I would like to render logout button with to end the session and route back to destination page. My navigation sitting under app.component.html, however please refer to

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from './_services/storage.service';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private roles: string[] = [];
  isLoggedIn = false;
  showAdminBoard = false;
  showModeratorBoard = false;
  username?: string;

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.storageService.isLoggedIn();

    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      const user = this.storageService.getUser();
      this.roles = user.roles;

      this.showAdminBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
      this.showModeratorBoard = this.roles.includes('ROLE_MODERATOR');

      this.username = user.username;
    }
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.storageService.clean();

        window.location.reload();
      },
      error: err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I want to be able to log the user out after passing the cookies.

Here is a demo project on stackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/token-jyzkww .

Comment: Thanks for the edit, halfer:)

Any recommendation for the code though?